# Is there a way or a bash script through JENKINS to give me the name of the folder in which the files were modified after a push?

Tags: bash, github, jenkins

i am a beginner in the DEVOPS field and I have a "trial" repo in github which i'm tracking through Jenkins
[here is the folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtUy7.png)

i would like to ask if there is any way(jenkins plugin or bash script) that if i modify a file in ok1,ok2, or ok3 folders and do a push, i get which folder was modified.

the result of the console's output shall be something like this :

"folder ok1 was changed"
or
"folder ok1 , ok2 were changed"
...etc

thank you

Comment: See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. You just need to set up the Git repo to trigger a build job on your Jenkins machine every time you push using the Github Jenkins webhook. You can read on how to do this [here](https://www.jenkins.io/solutions/github/)

Once the job successfully builds with every push, you can just do a [git-diff](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) to get the files that were changed. After that, its just a matter of extracting the folder name using regex or string manipulation.

Comment: thanks man that was very helpful .. i ended up using git show --stats to do the job and string manipulation as you recomanded to complete it .. thanks